# Setting a form variable value before submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where you can view a hotel's information. On this page is a little form to search for room availability for the hotel page you are on.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="search.asp" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="Hotel" name="Hotel" value="<%= HotelID %>">

    Arrive: <input value="<% strURLBookingDate %>" type="text" id="ArrivalDate" name="ArrivalDate">                            
    Depart: <input value="<% strURLBookingDate2 %>" type="text" id="DepartureDate" name="DepartureDate">

    <input type="submit" name="btnHotelSearch" value="Search This Hotel">
    <input type="submit" name="btnHotelSearchAll" value="Search All Hotels">                           
</form>
```

But I also need to add a button to the form that will allow me to search all hotels if I click it. For that to happen, I just need to set the hidden input value named "Hotel" to 0 when the button is clicked.

How can I set that hidden value before the form is submitted when I click btnHotelSearchAll?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can hook the `click` event on `btnHotelSearchAll` and then fill in the value:

```
document.getElementById("btnHotelSearchAll").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("Hotel").value = "0";
};
```

Be absolutely certain there's *nothing* else on the page that has either the `id` or `name` "Hotel", and that you don't have any global variables you've declared with that name, because some versions of IE [have bugs](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) where they conflate `name` values and global variable names into the namespace they use for `document.getElementById`. Or, alternately, make the `id` on the hidden field a bit more unique (the `name` can stay as it is so you don't have to change the backend; the `id` is only client-side, the `name` is what's sent to the server). E.g., you can do this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="HotelField" name="Hotel" value="<%= HotelID %>">
                              ^
```

and then change the code a bit:

```
document.getElementById("btnHotelSearchAll").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("HotelField").value = "0";
    //                            ^
};
```

---

**Update**:

Note that the code to hook up the button must run *after* the button has been put in the DOM. So with the code above, that means making sure that the script block is below the form in the page, like this:

```
<form ...>
....
</form>
...
<script>
...
</script>
```

If the `script` block is *above* the button, then the button won't exist yet as of when the script runs. This is one reason why it's frequently best to put scripts at the end of the `body` element, just before the closing `</body>` tag ([more here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)).

If you really want the script *above* the button, you have to delay the call by making it an `onload` event handler or that sort of thing. But `window.onload` happens *very* late in the process of a page load (it waits for *all* images and other assets to load, for instance), long after your users may be interacting with your form, so usually best to do it sooner.

---

**Off-topic**: My standard note that a lot of this stuff is made earlier and more robust by using a decent JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). jQuery, for instance, will deal with the IE bugs in `document.getElementById` for you so you don't have to worry about the conflation problem.

Comment: @Anders: LOL, I added an off-topic at the end that may make you retract that! :-) But I do justify it, and the main answer doesn't require any library (I don't believe in answering non-jQuery questions with jQuery-specific answers, but I do flag up how a decent library -- jQuery or other -- can be helpful).

Comment: For some reason this didn't work, the script never gets run when I click the button. Is there something else I need to do to get the code to fire?

Comment: @Steven: No, but I did forget to mention that you need to be sure the code runs *after* the button element is already in the DOM. I've updated to explain that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that id is only client-side and name gets sent to the server, wasn't aware of that and wondered why my POST-Variable was empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use jQuery, try the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
  $('#btnHotelSearch').click(function(){
    $('#Hotel').val(0);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `onclick` attribute to call javascript function that will set the hidden field value

```
 <input type="submit" name="btnHotelSearchAll" value="Search All Hotels" onclick="SetHotelID();">

<script>
   function SetHotelID()
   {
      $('#Hotel').val('0');
   }
</script>
```

**Note** I am using `Jquery`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, let me know if this works...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="Hotel" name="Hotel" value="<%= HotelID %>">

Arrive: <input value="<% strURLBookingDate %>" type="text" id="ArrivalDate" name="ArrivalDate">                            
Depart: <input value="<% strURLBookingDate2 %>" type="text" id="DepartureDate" name="DepartureDate">

<input type="submit" name="btnHotelSearch" value="Search This Hotel">
<input type="submit" name="btnHotelSearchAll" value="Search All Hotels" onclick='document.getElementById("Hotel").value="0"'>
```