# How to make the difference between unckecked and disabled HTML checkboxes?

Tags: html, checkbox, disabled-input

I'm trying to get the values from some checkboxes. Some are unchecked, some are checked but disabled. In both these cases, no POST data will be sent to the server by the browser.

What I'm wondering, is how can I know that the checkbox was unchecked, or disabled but checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only check, if a checkbox was checked (send) or not (not send).

If you realy want to know this server side, you can make use of [`AJAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) or set a [hidden input before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597444/setting-a-form-variable-value-before-submitting).

You can check the state of the checkbox here

```
document.getElementById("myBox").disabled
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve JavaScript hacks, but it seems it's the only solution. For a minute I thought using the readonly attribute was fine but, although the checkbox is grayed out, it can still be changed.

Comment: If the user is not be able to change it, why not safe the state into a `Session`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the disabled checkbox values are never sent to POST. What I would do is make a small JS code to enable the checkboxes right before the form is sent, or use hidden fields which mimic the checkboxes' values.